# Syntax error in for loop

Tags: for-loop, oracle11g, ora-06550, pls-00103

Error starting at line 1 in command:

```
DECLARE
   x NUMBER := 0;
   counter NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..4 LOOP
      x := x + 1000;
      counter := counter + 1;
      INSERT INTO temp VALUES (x, counter, 'in OUTER loop');
      END;
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

Error report:

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 11, column 10:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
>
> loop
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:
> ```

Comment: Have you got the `END`, `END LOOP`, `END` nesting corect?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need PL/SQL for this insert pattern. The following works in pure SQL:

```
create table temp(x number, counter number, text varchar2(20));

insert into temp
select (rownum-1)*1000, rownum-1, 'in OUTER loop'
from dual
connect by level <=4;
```

Answer (score 2):

The first `END;` on line 11 should not be there:

```
DECLARE
   x NUMBER := 0;
   counter NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..4 LOOP
      x := x + 1000;
      counter := counter + 1;
      INSERT INTO temp VALUES (x, counter, 'in OUTER loop');
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

You would only need it if you had a sub-block around the `INSERT` (say), for example for specific exception handling.

It would also be better generally to specify the column names in the `INSERT`:

```
      INSERT INTO temp(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (x, counter, 'in OUTER loop');
```